# error rgding definition & no extension method for System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am going through tutorial at 4GuysFromRolla website regarding Sorting and Paging a Grid of Data in ASP.NET MVC 2 by Scott Mitchell. I am receiving an error CS1061: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'AddQueryStringParameters' and no extension method 'AddQueryStringParameters' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I am not sure if I need to add a dll reference or something else. Please could someone advise how to solve this thanks in advance. Also I downloaded the demo and there is no problem. error is in PagerLink.ascx file..routeData.AddQueryStringParameters(); // error pointing here

RouteValueDictionaryExtensions.cs looks like this (this is the helper file)...

```
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace Web
{
  public static class RouteValueDictionaryExtensions
  {
     public static RouteValueDictionary  
     AddQueryStringParameters(this RouteValueDictionary dict)
     {
       var querystring = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;

        foreach (var key in querystring.AllKeys)
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
                dict.Add(key, querystring.GetValues(key)[0]);

        return dict;
    }

    public static RouteValueDictionary ExceptFor(this RouteValueDictionary  
                dict, params string[] keysToRemove)
    {
        foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
            if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
                dict.Remove(key);

        return dict;
    }
}
```

}

Global.asax.cs looks like this...

```
enter code here
namespace GridDemosMVC
{
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
// visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
            UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
   );

  }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
}
```

I am also using Dynamic.cs file which is available at microsoft to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `using` statement and `<%@ Import` directive for the namespace with the extension method.

Alternatively, you can move the extension method into your project's namespace.

Comment: where? the reason I am asking because in the demo file there is no use of <%@ Import... When you say using statement do you mean using System.Web.Routing;? thanks

Comment: No; you need to import the namespace in which you made the extension method.  You can also import it in Web.config for the views.

Comment: I think what has happened somehow files have got mixed up when I was adding exiting item in shared files. So when add namespace were implemented it was saying <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" /> when my file name was GridDemosMVC. I just had a quick retry renaming these add namespace with further errors, quite a few, so I came to conclusion that I need to restart the project. Thanks for your help SLaks. Just one quesition before I close this incident in professional environment is it referable to use thrid parties files such as jqGrid or manual code something what Scott Mitchell is offering.

Comment: @Disco: Do not re-invent the wheel.  There is nothing wrong with using a good third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

add in PagerLink.ascx file
<%@ Import Namespace="your project name space" %>

Answer (score 0):

Refer the namespace web in 2 user controls (`PagerLink.ascx` & `SmartLink.ascx`) as shown below.

`<%@ Import Namespace="Web"%>`

If you have changed the existing namespace, use the appropriate namespace of your project.